# How can I create a persistent websocket connection to kinesis? (I assume using ec2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, amazon-kinesis

How would I go about creating a WS listener and streaming to Kinesis? I have seen api call examples with lambdas -> kinesis, but I am looking at something for a persistent connection.
I am the client of the websocket and have to send aa api token within 3 seconds, but I do not have to communicate other than that with the socket, I am the listener. I do not control the Websocket.

I can use a Websocket connection package and have a script written to connect and authenticate, just not sure how exactly this would be designed (i.e. it would never stop running, so there's no while loop unless I am wrong)

Comment: Hi Lauren, can you please explain what are you trying to do again? maybe a diagram using draw.io will help a little. Thanks.

Comment: I would say use Api GW, with lambda, or something... Websockets are supported, but really not sure if that fits your needs.